# Why Javascript code not working before the action of servlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have written the javascript code for client validation and then for backend, I have used servlet. Javascript code is not working and directly moving to servlet from JSP registration page.

Here is the code:

```js
function teacherValidateForm() {



  var tuid = document.getElementById("tuname");

  return validateTID(tuid);


}

function validateTID(tuid) {
  var message = "Username must start with a letter and must be of minimum 5 letters";
  if (!tuid.match(/^[[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9/._]*]{5,}$/)) {
    document.getElementById(ti).innerHTML = message;

    return false;
  } else return true;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="teachersignup" class="form-horizontal" action="tsignup" onsubmit="return teacherValidateForm()" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tuname" class="control-label col-md-4" style="color:#000; font-size:15px" id="username">User Name: </label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tuname" required="true" name="tusername" />&nbsp; <label id="ti"></label>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem

```
var tuid = document.getElementById("tuname");
```

Change it to

```
var tuid = document.getElementById("tuname").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write JS code in

> Window.onload()

it's load all JS file when window open

Comment: because the function is invoked when the submit button is triggered.  You don't need to do this.  In fact, I'd almost say this is wrong/has nothing to do with the issue